# fetch data failed TypeError: nasaPicLists is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm using redux to store data and component scribe the store,
I did define the data type as Array,
but I get from the previous state always object value.
where is the wrong with the reducer?

Here is my reducer code.

```
import {legacy_createStore } from 'redux'
import nasaApod from '../model/nasaApod';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    storage,
};


const reducer = (nasaPicLists:nasaApod[]=new Array<nasaApod>(), action: {'type':string,   nasaPicList:nasaApod[]}) :Array<nasaApod>=>{
let newNasaPic:nasaApod[];
console.log("reducer")
console.log((nasaPicLists as Array<nasaApod>));
console.log("reducer1")
console.log(action.nasaPicList??[]);

console.log(action.type)
switch(action.type){
    case "replace":
        newNasaPic = action.nasaPicList??[];
        break;
    case "add":
        newNasaPic = [...nasaPicLists,...action.nasaPicList];
        break;
    default:
        newNasaPic = nasaPicLists;
}
    return newNasaPic;
}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer); 

const nasaList = legacy_createStore(persistedReducer);
const persisstore = persistStore(nasaList);

export default {nasaList,persisstore}
```

Chorme Error :

```
    fetch data failed TypeError: nasaPicLists is not iterable
    at reducer (nasaList.ts:25:1)
    at persistReducer.js:147:1
    at Object.dispatch (redux.js:288:1)
    at jsonParseNasaApod (NasaCardPage.tsx:59:1)
    at NasaCardPage.tsx:43:1
```

Please Help me fix the error
No more errors

Comment: console.log((nasaPicLists as Array<nasaApod>));  // here is output Object Type